# How to kow data updation is done in CQL DataStax java driver

Tags: cassandra, cql3, datastax-java-driver

I am using DataStax java driver for CQL table data insert, update. My question is how will I know that a updation query was successfull through `ResultSet`.Following code is updating a record in table.

```
    PreparedStatement statement = session.prepare(query);
    BoundStatement bs = new BoundStatement(statement);
    ResultSet resultSet = session.execute(bs.bind(key));
```

Answer (score 2):

I highly advice not to enable tracing in production and use its results in your code as a verification. In cassandra world in general, if your update/insert call does not throw an exception, your update was successful. Whether or not your updated reflected in all replicas is another question. You should your C*'s tunable consistency and use higher consistency levels in your calls if you want more consistency.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you won't be able to get the information, still you can trace it via `enable tracing`, which can provide further information regarding that operation.

```
  ResultSet results = session.execute(query);
  ExecutionInfo executionInfo = results.getExecutionInfo();
  QueryTrace queryTrace = executionInfo.getQueryTrace();
```

For further information, will suggest you to go through this [documentation](http://www.datastax.com/doc-source/developer/java-driver/tracing_t.html) on tracing.

Comment: I think @arya is correct that `In cassandra world in general, if your update/insert call does not throw an exception, your update was successful`

Comment: exactly. In no where you can retrieve return info from UPSERT operation, whether it is SQL world or NoSQL world.

Comment: Don't use tracing in this way. This is really bad advice. You ask C* to perform an operation, you specify the consistency you want for the operation (one, quorum, etc.), and if C* can't perform the operation at the requested consistency it will tell you, otherwise you can assume that everything has gone well.